# package subfig adds overwriting label in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats

As said above, this MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig} % this breaks list of figures with overwriting labels

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
  \caption[Short caption for list of figures]{Long caption}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

when compiled with `pdflatex`, produces the following problem:

[image]

whereas without `subfig` package everything is fine.

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code posted above doesn't recreate the problem.

Comment: @HarishKumar Very strange, I checked again and the problem is there, as you can see from the image I posted. I use MikTeX 2.9 and I just updated all packages, what did you use to check?

Comment: Same miktex updated 3days ago. :) : http://i.stack.imgur.com/0cgav.png

Comment: Damn, now what? I also tried deleting the auxiliary files and disabling `-shell-escape` compiling option, problem still there. Is there any more cache I could delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug which existed in the caption package for about three days. So updating your TeX distribution should help, if version 2015-09-20 (or newer) of the caption package bundle is not part of your TeX distribution yet, either wait or update the `caption` package bundle manually [1].

See also: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/24/

[1] https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/branches/3.3/tex/

Comment: Tha package manager of my MikTeX says that `caption` was packaged on 2015-09-22, but al least your are giving me hope, I'll check your links.

Comment: Take a look at the logfile generated when compiling your document. The date of caption3.sty should be 2015-09-20. If it is 2015-09-17, MikTeX has picked the older, buggy version of caption3.sty, for whatever reason, maybe because of using a not-yet-updated CTAN mirror. (Unfortunately http://miktex.org/packages/caption does not mention the version.)

Comment: You are right, my log shows `Package: caption3 2015/09/17 v1.7-111`, thanks a lot for pointing out the issue in such detail. I've tried to update MikTeX from a few random servers but no one has the 2015/09/20 version of `caption` package, is it possible to manually update the package? How easy and trouble-free is a manual update?

Comment: Just locate caption3.sty on your hard drive and replace it with the one linked in my answer. That file is the only real difference between the caption bundle releases 2015-09-17 and 2015-09-20, so if you have 2015-09-17 installed it should be problem-free just to replace this file.

Comment: Nice, I just updated `caption3.sty` as you suggested and the problem disappeared, thanks!

Comment: Update: It seems that MilkTeX updated the caption package on 2015-09-29, so simply updating MikTeX packages should help now. (See http://miktex.org/packages/caption )