# Garbled entries on list of figures using subfloat

Tags: table-of-contents

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Figure A.]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{test1}}
\subfloat[Figure B.]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{test2}}
\caption{Figures A and B.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: error]

This overlapping only occurs if I use subfloats. Both lualatex and pdflatex give the same result.

I am a LyX user, so I would like to stick to what it offers (subfloats, in the case). Some simple fix in the preamble would be best.

Comment: Probably the recent bug in the `caption` package ([package subfig adds overwriting label in list of figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269754)), you just need to update.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.