# Text “figure” appearing after section number in Table of Figures

Tags: tables, floats, tocloft

I am having the same issue as MarkSvalov in [this post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:t-NK783wJQQJ:tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274089/text-figure-appearing-after-section-number-in-table-of-figures+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de).
Sadly it seems like it has been removed.

[image: figure]

The same thing is happening to the List of tables, but not to the listings (source code).

So what I am using is classicthesis.

I can just download the zip and build it with my TeXstudio and I'll get the exact same behaviour.

As I tried to cope with this issue for an hour now I already tested all the ctf pre and after commands. What I believe is that the word "figure" or "table" gets somehow into the section numbering.

If I take a look at the *.lof or *.lot file the content supports my findings:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1{figure}}{\ignorespaces SomeFigure}{9}{figure.caption.9}
```

As you can see {1{figure}} doesn't seem right.

I am really happy with TeXstudio, but I'll try another environment to see if it'll still occur.

Do you guys have any idea how I can disable this behaviour?

I read somewhere that people had problems with the automatic language detection of their latex Editor/IDE and some package called bable.

But I couldn't find any settings that would support this idea.

Maybe you guys can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome! Since this isn't the default behaviour, we cannot help without a small example of code we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. However, it has nothing to do with TeXStudio. That's just an editor. It doesn't compile anything and any other editor will use exactly the same software to compile your code, with just the same results. It doesn't have anything to do with **babel** either, if that's what you mean. (As in Babel Fish.)

Comment: The package you mention is `babel` ( from the eponymous polyglot tower).

Comment: That is, we can only say to you what Kurt said there to MarkSvalov. Somewhere in your code is an error. Without the code, that's all we can say. Except that the error has to do with the writing of the `.lot` and `.lof` entries. But unless you want to correct those by hand, that's not much help.

Comment: That was a typo. My bad. I meant babel.

Comment: @Bernard Sure, but the Babel Fish is better known ;).

Comment: Well, as I said. I can download a fresh copy of "classicthesis" and the same error will appear. So that's kind of the example code I can give you.

Comment: This should tell you something about the wisdom of using classicthesis. If even the sample document doesn't compile, do you really want to use it?

Comment: Also, why are you downloading it? The package is part of standard TeX distributions (e.g. TeX Live, presumably MikTeX).

Comment: [Here's the output I get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HoYeR.png) when I compile the sample document (for the lists of figures, tables etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am not that experienced with latex yet. But I can't switch now anyways. Too late for that :-D So [this is what I get](http://imgur.com/LhlgshJ). I already updated Miktex. And [this](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) is the sample I downloaded.

Comment: You mentioned I could correct them manually. That would be something I could live with, as I'd just have to do it once. So I would just use a search and replace to correct the malformed parts, but how can I tell pdflatex to use an existing *.lot or *.lof instead of compiling a new one?

Comment: No. If you correct them in the `.lot` and `.lof`, you will have to do so every time you compile. You will then compile again and they should come out correctly (but the `.lot` and `.lof` will now be mangled again so another compilation will produce the erroneous output). Compiling the example from the documentation should not produce the output you posted. Period. That source does not produce the output you show. You must have something mixed in with it e.g. a buggy configuration file or similar.

Comment: Try deleting all generated files and recompiling. What does `kpsewhich classicthesis-config.tex` give?

Comment: Update! your! Tex! distribution! now!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269749/package-subfig-adds-overwriting-label-in-list-of-figures  If this doesn't fix your issue, please post the log file, especially the version of caption3.sty used.

Comment: Please calm down. I already answered my own question. Of course I updated my distribution. It was the first thing I did. But like I said, wiping it clean was the way to go. Updating wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, at least I figured out how to get rid of the issue, although I couldn't quite find the origin of it.

First of all thank you very much for your help @cfr .

As I tried to compile a fresh sample of classicthesis and the error still kept popping up, I switched to my linux distribution and successfully hit the pdflatex to create an error free version.

On Windows the error still occured with MikTex, so after that I completely wiped everything and reinstalled the environment. No error occurs. Even though I am using the exact same latex source files.

So what I'd suggest if you come across this problem, try to delete all the auto generated files, if it still doesn't help, test it in another environment (maybe you got a Virtual Machine laying around?).

Hope this helps.

Best regards.