# List of Figures and Tables are appending extra words

Tags: table-of-contents

Using "book" class and calling \listoffigures to generate the figure index. But the output shown is:

1.1figure sometitle1

1.2figure sometitle2

Wish to remove the additional word "figure" getting attached to the index numbers. How?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Figures}
There are several ways to plot a function of two variables, depending on the information you are interested in. For instance, if you want to see the mesh of a function so it easier to see the derivative you can use a plot  like the one on the left.

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{lion-logo}
\caption{My logo}
\label{logo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you comment inclusion of "subfig" then it works fine, else not.

In MWE I am not using subfig but in my actual report, I am.

Comment: We've had a similar question here: [How to delete the prefix 'figure" from LoF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296487/5764) ...however, we'd like to replicate the results to understand what might be the root cause. Perhaps you can provide a minimal example that shows what's going on?

Comment: With or without [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) in your minimal example I get not `figure` in the LoF. Can you [show us the versions of the packages](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X) you're using?

Comment: Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

Comment: Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package

Comment: Package: caption 2015/09/17 v3.3-111 Customizing captions (AR)

Comment: package `subcaption` would have been a better choice ;-)

Comment: Looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269749/package-subfig-adds-overwriting-label-in-list-of-figures so updating the `caption` package should help.