# Remove "figure" from List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following problem: `\listoffigures` display

**1figure Description of the figure.**

I want to remove "figure" so it looks like this:

**1 Description of the figure.**

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like a wrong use of `\caption` etc. Please provide a working document that shows this feature, not just an error 'description'

Answer (score 0):

Update your TeX distribution and the problem will go away.

See also: [package subfig adds overwriting label in list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269749/package-subfig-adds-overwriting-label-in-list-of-figures)