# Lyx Table of Contents formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I have inserted a table of contents but have found when I create a pdf of the file the formatting is not good with the figure number over the image name.
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Jo! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think this is a problem caused by a bug in the `caption` package that was present in some version. If you upgrade that package it should work fine.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269749/package-subfig-adds-overwriting-label-in-list-of-figures/269754#269754 (@ebo as well, for that matter)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed, I was not aware of it (since my "standard" comment). Thank you for tagging me in the comment!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was resolved by a package update.